# How to have better transition between Splash Screen and Program in Frame buffer?

Tags: linux, qt, framebuffer, yocto

I am currently using Yocto Embedded Linux with frame buffer.  When the machine is boot up, there is a splash screen.  After the the splash screen, I will run `rc.local` to autostart my program.

The thing is, when I execute the program, there will be about 1-2 second initialization.  This will result in getting no signal from the board and have a black screen.

Is it possible to set up something so that those 1-2 second will not be black?  I could put the splash screen up during that time.

What is the reason behind those 1-2 seconds initialization?